# Content-Type request header error handling not returning correctly

Tags: python, flask

I created a Flask error handler which will return 415 if Content-Type is not application/json. However, even if I selected an incorrect Content-Type in my Postman tool, I still get 200 response when it should return an error message. What could be the problem?

Here is my code in app.py

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.errorhandler(415)
def unsupported_media(error):
    content_type = request.content_type('Content-Type')
    if 'Content-Type' in request.headers and content_type != 'application/json':
        return make_response(jsonify(error = 'Content-Type is required to be application/json'), 415)
```

I also setup incorrect Content-Type value in my postman

Update:
I tried this code and it worked. However, Im not sure if this is a correct implementation. Should I still use the app.errorhandler()?

```
@app.before_request 
def unsupported_media():
if not request.is_json: 
     return jsonify(Error = 'Content-Type is required to be application/json'), 415
```

Comment: try to add an `else` statement also.

Answer (score 0):

updated:

`errorhandler` is to handle `error`, e.g., `HTTPException` from `werkzug`.
You can just make response in the `before_request` handler without handler the `415 exception`.

---

> `errorhandler` Register a function to handle errors by code or exception class.

Maybe `before_request` is what you need.

```py
from flask import Flask, request, abort


app = Flask(__name__)

# This will register the validate function to all the endpoint
@app.before_request
def _is_json():
    if not request.is_json:
        abort(415, 'Content-Type is required to be application/json')

@app.errorhandler(415)
def unsupported_media(error):
    return {'error': error.description}

"""
YOUR router view functions or classes
"""
```

Comment: Is this a safe implementation? If not, could you help me improve this code more @app.before_request
def unsupported_media():
    if not request.is_json:
        return jsonify(Error = 'Content-Type is required to be application/json'), 415

Comment: You should be more specific. I do not understand what you mean about 'safe implementation'. And the code you posted is not readable. You can edit your question and describe it in more detail.

Comment: I updated my post, you can view my recent changes. Thank you!

Comment: I've updated my post to answer your question.

Comment: How can I reuse the code you posted for other error code e.g. 400, 404? Or should I duplicate the methods you posted for other error code

Comment: You may want to check the [documents](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/reqcontext/?highlight=before_request#callbacks-and-errors) about lifetime cycle. If you is to handle the error code, you should use `errorhandler`. If you is about to return the error response eariler, you should use the `before_request`, `after_request` or whatever `callback decorator`.